# My own function for copying memory in C

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, memory-management

I have written a function that copies memory from one destination to another. I would like you to view my code and tell me if I have to fix something. That's the code:

```
void* memCopy(void* destination, const void* source, size_t size)
{
    double *a = (double*)source, *b = (double*)destination;
    void* end = a + (size / sizeof(double));
    while ((void*)a < end)
    {
        *b = *a;
        ++a;
        ++b;
    }
    char* a2 = (char*)a;
    char* b2 = (char*)b;
    end = a2 + (size % sizeof(double));
    while (a2 < end)
    {
        *b2 = *a2;
        ++a2;
        ++b2;
    }
    return destination;
}
```

I have used `double*` to make the function faster.

Comment: I'm not a fan of `while` loops for anything other than (near-)infinite loops. Is there a reason you used them instead of `for` loops? For reference, [this is how one version of `memcpy` does it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17591624/1014587).

Comment: @Mast agree-ish; but not because I have a specific aversion to `while`; rather because `for` is specifically a better fit here since it has a clear loop counter

Comment: The K&R approach would probably be "while((void *)a < end) { *b++ = *a++;}" ;-)

Comment: If you look at the source for many x86 versions, you'll see that it 'top and tails' the copies on alignment boundaries, and then uses larger moves in the middle.   Similar to how you are handling the end case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile cleanly with GCC:

```
move.c: In function 'memCopy':
move.c:16:15: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast
     while (a2 < end)
               ^
```

Also 2 brief points:

1. Why reinvent the wheel? Most implementations of memcpy, memmove etc in the standard libraries will be correctly and efficiently implemented, in many cases not using pure C.
2. Your code assumes that both source and data are correctly aligned to be accessed as double. If they are not, depending on the platform the code may a) perform badly, b) give incorrect results or c) simply crash, unless I'm much mistaken. It happens to run (apparently correctly) on my PC, but that's no guarantee of portability.

[The FreeBSD implementation](https://www.leidinger.net/FreeBSD/dox/libkern/html/dc/dba/bcopy_8c_source.html) shows how this can be done, assuming that that the mapping of pointers to `uintptr_t` gives values which can be masked appropriately - this is true of the relevant targets of the code, but may not be universally so.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I'd guess that Ivan tested on some form of x86, which is very forgiving about unaligned access.  Most processors will bus fault at best.

Comment: Mark,  Hmm, FreeBSD uses `if ((unsigned long)dst < (unsigned long)src) {`.  I'd expect `if ((uintptr_t)dst < (uintptr_t)src) {`, that it is a bug when `uintptr_t` is wider than `unsigned long`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I doubt that uintptr_t was even a twinkle in a C developer's eye when that code was developed - it's pretty ancient. I suspect that until it fails, it'll be left as is. As your answer mentions, it does deal with overlaps by appropriate directional copying. I didn't comment on the use of double, as you do, as I wasn't totally sure of my ground, but I agree with your concerns.

Comment: @MarkBluemel My recommendation does not introduce `uintptr_t` usage as the linked code already uses `uintptr_t` in `if ((t | (uintptr_t)dst) & wmask) {`.  Unfortunately it does not use `uintptr_t` uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Mark Bluemel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/259196/29485) good answer:

**Overlap**

A difference between `memcpy()` and `memmove()` is the ability to handle overlapping buffers.  Notice the keyword `restrict`.

```
void *memcpy(void * restrict s1, const void * restrict s2, size_t n);
void *memmove(void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);
```

`restrict` roughly implies access to the buffer is not interfered with by other activity.

`memCopy()` code does not copy well overlapping buffers when the `source` precedes the `destination`.  It is more like

```
void* memCopy(void* restrict destination, const void* restrict source, size_t size)
```

By using `restrict`, the compiler can invoke additional optimizations.

A solution to act like `memmove()` involves looping up or down depending on which is greater `source` or  `destination`.  The trick is that this compare for pointer greatness is not certainly possible in C.  `memmove()`, as a library function, has access to information C does not.  Yet a compare of pointers converted to an integer is *usually* sufficient.

**Types**

`double` is *not* the way to go.  `*b = *a;` is not guaranteed to copy the bit pattern nor potentially triggering a signaling not-a-number exception.  Best to avoid involving floating-point concerns.  Instead use a wide unsigned integer type, perhaps `uintmax_t`, `unsigned long long`, or `uint64_t`.  (Pros and cons for each.  I'd go for `uint64_t` when available.)

<strike>On ancient machines, `*b2 = *a2;` can invoke a *trap*.  Instead use `unsigned char *a2; unsigned char *b2;`</strike>

**Zero size**

`memCopy(..., ..., 0)` is properly handled.  Bravo! - a common mistake avoided here.